# Can .htpasswd have user groups and can PHP read them?

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

if `.htpasswd` contains `joe:password` and `.htaccess` uses basic authentication and you log in as Joe, then
`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` / `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` / `$_ENV['PHP_AUTH_USER']` / `$_ENV['REMOTE_USER']` all become `joe`.

But what if you want your code to allow something just to a certain group?

i.e. Can you divide your users to groups right inside `.htpasswd` (e.g. `accountant:joe:password`), then have PHP grab the group?

Comment: No, that is not possible with mod_auth_basic or mod_auth_digest, those do not know any concept of user "groups".

Comment: But you can create an array in PHP, if you like - group name as key, value would be an array of user names. Then you can loop over that, and check if the user name you read from those environmental/server variables, is in one of those groups ...

Answer (score 1):

The Apache module that can provide HTTP basic auth with file storage backend and group support is [mod_authz_groupfile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_groupfile.html), but groups have to be defined in a separate file:

```
admins: amy bill
support: charlie david edward
guests: fernando ivonne
```

But I believe groups are something internal to Apache and they aren't exposed to PHP, let alone the browser. From the PHP standpoint, if you have physical access to data files, you always can get the information by yourself:

```
$rawGroups = file('/path/to/.htgroup');
$usersByGroup = [];
foreach ($rawGroups as $rawGroup) {
    if (!preg_match('/^\s*(?P<group>[\S]+)\s*:\s*(?P<users>.+)\s*$/', $rawGroup, $matches)) {
        continue;
    }
    $usersByGroup[$matches['group']] = preg_split('/\s+/', $matches['users']);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/heD2Y)

If you don't really need to have Apache involved, then just create your own homebrew group system.

Comment: Cann you add a second part of figuring out the group? i.e. `foreach ($usersByGroup as $key=>$value) foreach ($value as $value2) if ($value2==$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) {$the_group = $key; break 2;}`? Also, if you just want to know if the user exists or not: `$found = false; foreach ($usersByGroup as $value) if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'], $value)) {$found = true; break;}`